# ReactJS Assigning Value inside a class component method to props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to access the index of the selected tab in a React component so as to map it to props as follows:

```
class AttendanceDetail extends React.Component {

handleSelect(key, props) {

    console.log(key)

    props.index = key;

}


render(){

    const {single_class, courses, attendances} = this.props;

    // console.log(this.state);
    if(single_class) {
        return(
        <div className='container content-section'>

            // Some irrelevant Code  

            <Tabs defaultActiveKey={0} onSelect={this.handleSelect} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">

            { courses.map((course, index) => {


                return (
                <Tab eventKey={index} title={course.course  + " year " + course.yearofstudy}>

                 //Other irrelevant code...

                </Tab>
                )
            })}   
            </Tabs>

        </div>
        )
    } else {

    return (
        <div className='container content-section'>
        Loading Unit details... 
        </div>
    );

    }

}

}
```

So basically the `handleSelect` method is what determines the index of the selected tab and logs it to the console. The problem is, I'm tring to map that key (index) to props so as to access it else where but to no avail. Could someone help me out? What am I missing?

Comment: Where would you be trying to access it? Maybe you should consider redux?

Comment: Basically what I want is to map that index to props @rrd so as to access it in a HOC

Comment: @Abedy why do you want to map 'index' to props why not use state and then pass the state as a prop?

Comment: I've tried that using the `mapStatToProps()` but it still doesn't  work still. Would you probably do some illustration with some piece of code? @Dheeraj

Comment: @Abedy do you have active class set on your tab component? or anything to distinguish the open tab from the closed tab?

Comment: @Dheeraj Yes. The index. Basically the tab objects have been mapped from an array and thus each object has an index

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to set the component's `props`, only read. You can use `state` within the component:

```
export class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            index: 0 //initial state
        }
    }
    handleSelect(index, props) {
        this.setState({index})
    }
    render() {
        return (
           <span>{this.state.index}</span>
        )
    }
}
```

you can read more on the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Say I want to use that state outside the class component. Say in a `mapStateToProps` method outside the class. How would you pass that state? Because I've tried your approach too and I can't seem to capture that index.

Comment: You can add a prop to this component in the parent component `<AttendanceDetail changeIndexCallback={this.handleSelect}/>` and in the `AttendanceDetail` component call the function like this `this.props.handleSelect(newIndex)`. This way you have the index state in `AttendanceDetail`'s parent component.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood the scenario correctly, you need to log `index` value of the currently active tab. try using `onFocus` event handler to get the index value of the currently visible tab and set the state that will be used by handleSelect

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
  this.state = {
    index:''
  }
}
```

the handler definition

```
setIndex = (index) => {
  this.setState({index})
}
```

update handleSelect

```
handleSelect(index) {
    console.log(index)
    // call event handler of parent component eg: this.props.getIndex(index);
}
```

update tabs component handler

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey={0} onSelect={() => {this.handleSelect(this.state.index)}} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
```

call handler on focus of tab

```
<Tab 
onFocus={() => {this.setIndex(index)}} 
eventKey={index} 
title={course.course  + " year " + course.yearofstudy}>

//Other irrelevant code...
</Tab>
```

Comment: Not log the index rather, but map that index to props

Comment: You cannot update the props, props are immutable. you should use states for all mutable data